# linq with entity order by desc

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I just want to order descending like this:

```
var query = from o in oEntite_T.ORDRE
            where o.DATE_CREE >= datedeb && o.DATE_CREE <= datefin
            orderby o.NO_ORDRE descending
            select o;
```

It does not order descending, and I also tried:

```
var query = (from o in oEntite_T.ORDRE
             where o.DATE_CREE >= datedeb && o.DATE_CREE <= datefin
             select  o).OrderByDescending(p => p.NO_ORDRE);
```

I got the same result. Is this because the component Devexpress?

```
linqServerModeSource_Ordre.KeyExpression = "NO_ORDRE;CODE_CLIENT";
linqServerModeSource_Ordre.QueryableSource = oOrdre_BL.Get_OrdreEntity(dateEdit_Deb_Ordre.DateTime, dateEdit_Fin_Ordre.DateTime);

gridControl_Liste_Ordres.DataSource = linqServerModeSource_Ordre;
```

My complete code:

```
public IQueryable<ORDRE> Get_OrdreEntity(DateTime datedeb, DateTime datefin)
{
    try
    {
        IQueryable<ORDRE> LesListe;
        Soft8Exp_ClientEntities oEntite_T = new Soft8Exp_ClientEntities();

        var query = (from o in oEntite_T.ORDRE
                     where o.DATE_CREE >= datedeb && o.DATE_CREE <= datefin
                     select  o).OrderByDescending(p => p.NO_ORDRE);
        //var query = oEntite_T.ExecuteFunction<ORDRE>("qf").;

        LesListe = query;
        return LesListe;
    }
    catch (Exception excThrown)
    {
        throw new Exception("Err_02", excThrown);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to debug what the dB query is returning to check where the order is being changed. Your code should return the items in the order you expected them.

Comment: it is true when i debug the query return what i want.

Comment: Sorry that sentence doesn't make sense. 
When you debug your code, are the items being returned from the database in the order you want? 
If so then the issue is with the DevExpress Control, which must be reordering them.

Comment: yes, dB query is returning descending.

Answer (score 1):

From the code I see that you return the query object to some external infrastructure (set DataSource property of a devexpress component).
Then I'd day that this component just adds another .OrderBy to this query when it executes it object so your sorting is lost.

It seems to be very possible and logical since devexpress have their own sorting capabilities which seem to just override yours.

By setting DataSource you just provide a data set, and it is up to the component to add sorting, paging, etc.

So look at the component API in order to specify sorting that you need. Perhaps it has properties to do it.